# How to call a root handler from the router?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a Router code:

```
var HellospaceRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ""      :   "root", 
        "signup":   "signup",  
        "login" :   "login"
    }
});
```

These handlers change the model state. Changing the state of the model makes redraw View. First handler not called...

**UPD**

[Code](http://pastebin.com/tPHCbRgk)

Comment: Do you have a `Backbone.history.start()` call somewhere?

Comment: I assume you are also instantiating the router at some point? Could you post any other code that is involved in router/history setup?

Comment: I get it. I just added a call model.trigger('change') after creating a view. And the root handler has to work... But the last two handlers had been working. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I really need to see more of the code to give you a proper answer...